# Swift: fill AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSDictionary?>

Tags: swift, ios8, dtcoretext

I am DTCoreText to transform HTML to attributed text. Because I want to set the font up front, not afterwards as that would override all bold, italic etcetera tags I want to set the document attributes in the constructor. This constructors wants me to give a AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer that more or less seems to be a NSDictionary? with & up front. Sort of. Only it doesn't let me set it in any way. I've tried .memory, tried to cast the dictionary in any possible way and it just doesn't accept any data.

```
    let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
    let data = info.desc?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let attributes: NSMutableDictionary? = NSMutableDictionary()
    attributes!.setObject(font, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
    var attributeRef: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSDictionary?> = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer.null()
    NSMutableAttributedString(HTMLData: data, documentAttributes: nil)
    //attributeRef = *attributeDict
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(HTMLData: data, documentAttributes:attributeRef)
    let paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping;
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: range)
    lblMessage.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: Are you aware that DTCoreText is no longer needed? iOS now lets you turn HTML to NSAttributedString directly.

Comment: Thanks matt! The native call unfortunately still requires the same AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer :(

Comment: Just say `var dict = NSDictionary?()` and pass `&dict`. Or `nil` if you don't need the resulting dictionary.

Comment: My misunderstanding was that I thought the dictionary would set anything, but it doesn't. It only returns. So it's useless in this context but I will try it anyway just for future reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not be using DTCoreText at this point; iOS now has native calls for this. Just say `var dict = NSDictionary?()` and pass `&dict`. Here's example code:

```
let s = "<html><body><h1>Howdy</h1><p>Hello</p></body></html>"
let d = s.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
var dict = NSDictionary?()
let att = NSAttributedString(data: d!, options: [
    NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType
    ], documentAttributes: &dict, error: nil)
println(att!)
println(dict!)
```

You'll see that this works perfectly well. Here is `dict`:

```
BottomMargin = 72;
Converted = "-1";
DocumentType = NSHTML;
LeftMargin = 90;
PaperMargin = "UIEdgeInsets: {72, 90, 72, 90}";
PaperSize = "NSSize: {612, 792}";
RightMargin = 90;
TopMargin = 72;
UTI = "public.html";
```

However, I usually pass `nil` because nothing is coming back in the second dictionary that I really care about.

Comment: Note this doesn't set the default font for the HTML as the OP is asking about. `NSAttributedString` APIs don't do that for HTML, so most people go for just adding font specification to the HTML/CSS before throwing it at `NSAttributedString`: [here's an example](http://jmduke.com/posts/markdown-in-swift/).

Comment: @rickster Or you could form the attributed string and then cycle through the style runs changing the font.

Comment: @DepartamentoB I believe I've answered the basic question you asked, namely how to deal with the `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSDictionary?>`.

Comment: Yeah you did, didn't have the time to implement it. Trying in 5 hours from now :)

Answer (score 3):

To update fonts in generated HTML use the code similar to the following:

**Swift 5**

```
extension String {

    /// Convert HTML to NSAttributedString
    func convertHtml() -> NSAttributedString {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
            let string = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)

            // Apply text color
            string.addAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.text], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))

            // Update fonts
            let regularFont = UIFont(name: Fonts.Regular, size: 13)! // DEFAULT FONT (REGUALR)
            let boldFont = UIFont(name: Fonts.Bold, size: 13)! // BOLD FONT
            /// add other fonts if you have them

            string.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length), options: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0), using: { (value, range, stop) -> Void in

                /// Update to our font
                // Bold font
                if let oldFont = value as? UIFont, oldFont.fontName.lowercased().contains("bold") {
                    string.removeAttribute(.font, range: range)
                    string.addAttribute(.font, value: boldFont, range: range)
                }
                // Default font
                else {
                    string.addAttribute(.font, value: regularFont, range: range)
                }
            })
            return string
        }
        return NSAttributedString()
    }
}
```